# Check for all used OpenGL Extensions

Tags: c++, opengl, virtualization, portability

I'm using GLEE in my application and everything works just fine on regular Windows.

However, when running under virtualization my application does not work properly. Either it crashes or just renders black. This is probably due to some OpenGL extension missing. I have tried to identify all the used extensions and check for the during program startup so that it warns the user. This have worked out in the case of the crash. However, in the render black case I don't get any extension missing warning. I suspect this is because I have missed checking for some extension. So my question is.

Is there any good way to identify **all** the OpenGL extensions that are used in an application so that one might add checks for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, but it will be a bit of work.

GLEE offers lazy loading, so you should be able to trivially modify it to log each function that is called. The lazy loading code (I have not looked at it, admittedly, but it is probably something similar) probably looks something like:
if(funcptr == 0) { _ _ glee_load_fp(funcptr, _ _ FUNCTION _ _) } funcptr(args); .

So, what you would have to do first would be to log all functions that you actually call in this manner, and then you would have to do a reverse lookup mapping function names to extensions. Normally that would mean to parse glext.spec, which is a horror. But luckily, you can download an xml representation of everything that's inside GLEE from the GLEE website, which is much, much nicer to work with.

Comment: This will work only for extensions that introduce new procedures. Extensions like GL_ARB_cubemap which only introduce new tokens will not be covered using this.

Comment: That's right, I didn't think of extensions that merely introduce new constants (or GLSL instructions, such as texgrad). Though I can't imagine how one would find out programatically whether or not one has used one of them unknowingly. Well, one could write a parser that goes over the entire source code and extracts all tokens that start with either GL_ or gl (and, possibly wgl and glx as well). In fact, I guess someone with a certain level of sed-fu could probably do that without writing a program for it. Then all that would be left would be the matching with the xml spec.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at GLEW for extensions as well / instead.

It provides macros to query implemented extensions.

http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html

Comment: Yes, that is the canonical thing to use at startup, but this presumes that ronag knows which extensions are used, which apparently is not the case.

Comment: @dm.skt: Which shows that roang was too lazy: One always tests for the availability of needed facilities. One can't just assume that there's a bridge over the rift there and accelerate full throttle toward the cliff. If the program requires say OpenGL-2.1 features at least check the version number reported by glGetString(GL_VERSION)

Comment: I wouldn't call myself lazy. I check for all the extension that I am aware that my program is using. However, I might have missed some extension. Which is why I'd like to programmaticality check which extensions are used.